# How do I choose a multicast address for my application? (It will be over the internet, not internal)

Tags: sockets, ip, multicast

How do I choose a multicast address for my app? I don't want to clash with other apps, but I assume that there must be enough apps by now that every multicast address is in use by something. Do I just choose any random address in the 224.0.1.186 - 224.0.1.255 range?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5771) on this.

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly, then I can choose any address between 232.0.0.0 and 232.0.0.8, right? (I'm making an app that's only cares about the info from my server, so I'd do a "Source-Specific Multicast Block", correct?)